# Группа Альфа - заглавная буква и кавычки

Tags: кавычки, названия

Столкнулась с таким затруднением. Подразделение бойцов (условно) разделено на группы - альфа и бета. Надо ли заключать их названия в кавычки и писать с заглавной буквы? С одной стороны, это не юридические названия, а условное деление бойцов на две группы, по сути, они части одного большого воинского коллектива. С другой - это все-таки название (позывные) групп и напрашивается написание с заглавной буквы. Буду признательна за помощь!